# Invocation of EJB deployed on JBoss 4.3 from EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

Migrating application from JBoss4.3 to JBoss EAP6.1

Would like to invoke a remote EJB which is deployed on JBoss 4.3....tried several ways, getting lot of errors..

Please provide the steps to invoke EJB(running on JBoss4.3) from JBoss EAP.

Comment: Try using the `AluniteClassloader`. Related [article](http://wolf-71.blogspot.com/2010/02/et-phone-home.html) and [project](https://github.com/wolfc/jboss-alunite).